# how to access local files from ionic iOS app for uploading video and audio

Tags: ios, ionic3

Actually I'm using iOS file picker for uploading audio and video files from my app. Is there any way to access local files from any app? Is it possible or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check file directory structure to upload a file for iOS. The link is: 
https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file#where-to-store-files 
You can read iOS local file using `cordova.file.documentsDirectory`